# gray shade on jfreechart when scroll the swt Scrollcomposite

Tags: user-interface, swt, jfreechart

I have many jfree line graphs inside a swt scrolled composite under a view. When I scroll an come back again the graph is getting gray shade on it. This problem is not coming in the combination of Java 1.6 and Galileo. When I try with Neon and Java 1.8 I am getting this issue.

I have tried with all below versions of jfree chart.

```
jfreechart-1.0.14
jfreechart-1.0.19
jfreechart-1.5.0
```

code snippet below.

```
JFreeChart chart = jfreeChartTest.createCategoryChart(null,groupText,0,1, -1);
Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);
ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart); 

 chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(415, 300));
 chartPanel.setMouseZoomable(true, false);

 frame.add(chartPanel);
```

[image]

Comment: JFreeChart chart = jfreeChartTest.createCategoryChart(null,groupText,0,1, -1);
 Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);
 ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart); 
 
  chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(415, 300));
  chartPanel.setMouseZoomable(true, false);
  
  frame.add(chartPanel);

Comment: you can try to set `renderer.setShadowsVisible(false);` in map code.